# I have been stuck in this Twilioquest problem for hours and it includes arrays. How do I solve it?

Tags: javascript

So I recently downloaded TwilioQuest to try and learn programming properly. It's going pretty well and I think it's a great game to learn programming but, I got stuck in a problem.

To pass to the next part of the game, I need to make a program that includes a function which takes in a single array command line argument and adds the first index of the array to the last. It gave me some starting code in case I needed it but even in that I am confused. This is the starting code it gave me:

```js
function addFirstToLast(inputArray) {
  let firstAndLast = '';

  // Only execute this code if the array has items in it
  if (inputArray.length > 0) {
    // Change the line below! What should it be?
    firstAndLast = inputArray[999] + inputArray[999];
  }

  return firstAndLast;
}

// The lines of code below will test your function when you run it from the
// command line with Node.js
console.log(addFirstToLast(['first', 'second', 'third']));
console.log(addFirstToLast(['golden', 'terrier']));
console.log(addFirstToLast(['cheerio']));
console.log(addFirstToLast([]));
```

I just don't understand what I have to put in the first lines of code where it says, let firstAndLast = '';

This is what I added to the code:

```js
function addFirstToLast(inputArray) {
  let firstAndLast = inputArray[0] + inputArray[-1];

  // Only execute this code if the array has items in it
  if (inputArray.length > 0) {
    // Change the line below! What should it be?
    firstAndLast = inputArray[0] + inputArray[-1];
  }

  return firstAndLast;
}

// The lines of code below will test your function when you run it from the
// command line with Node.js
console.log(addFirstToLast(['first', 'second', 'third']));
console.log(addFirstToLast(['golden', 'terrier']));
console.log(addFirstToLast(['cheerio']));
console.log(addFirstToLast([]));
```

However, it gives me this output:

```
firstundefined
goldenundefined
cheerioundefined
NaN
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: what is the expected out ?

Comment: The expected output is concatenating the first and last index of the array, like so. "['cats', 'dogs', 'birds']" output: catsbirds

Comment: Can you state the problem state more clearly? What should be the return value of the function? and adding 1st index or 1st element to the last?

Comment: Maybe `firstAndLast = inputArray[0] + (inputArray.length > 1 ? inputArray[inputArray.length -1]:'');`

Comment: The return value should be firstAndLast, like returning the first and last elements of the array but made into one word. like cats and dogs into catsdogs.

Comment: @SpiderDev_m8 Follow Satpal comment . you will get the desired results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow.

I think the line of code you're looking for here is this:

```
firstAndLast = inputArray[0] + inputArray[inputArray.length-1];
```

This will create a string with the value from the first element of the array concatenated with the value from the last element of the array (even if these are the same in the case of a length of 1). The first 'if' statement is to avoid the situation of having passed in an array with no items (like this []).

Answer (score 0):

For concatenating the first and last element of the array
`inputArray[0] + inputArray[inputArray.length-1]`

```
function addFirstToLast(inputArray) {
  let firstAndLast = ""
   
  // Only execute this code if the array has items in it
  if (inputArray.length > 0) {
    // Change the line below! What should it be?
    let first = inputArray[0]
    let last = inputArray.length === 1 ? "" : inputArray[inputArray.length - 1]
    firstAndLast = first + last;
  }

  return firstAndLast;
}

// The lines of code below will test your function when you run it from the
// command line with Node.js
console.log(addFirstToLast(['first', 'second', 'third']));
console.log(addFirstToLast(['golden', 'terrier']));
console.log(addFirstToLast(['cheerio']));
console.log(addFirstToLast([]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function addFirstToLast(inputArray) {
  let firstAndLast = '';
  if (inputArray.length > 0) {
      firstAndLast = inputArray[0] + inputArray.pop();
  }

  return firstAndLast;
}

console.log(addFirstToLast(['first', 'second', 'third']));
console.log(addFirstToLast(['golden', 'terrier']));
console.log(addFirstToLast(['cheerio']));
console.log(addFirstToLast([]));
```

I'm not sure if this is how they wanted it done but it's how I completed the task.
The code starts be defining the firstAndLast variable as empty.
It then checks if the list has more than zero items.
If it does, it moves on. If not, the variable stays empty.
It then adds the first item in inputArray to the variable firstAndLast using inputArray[0]
Then it uses inputArray.pop which extracts the last item from the list and places it in the variable.

Hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
function addFirstToLast(inputArray) {
let firstAndLast = '';
// Only execute this code if the array has items in it
if (inputArray.length > 0) {
  // Change the line below! What should it be?
  firstAndLast = inputArray[0] + inputArray[inputArray.length - 1];    
}

return firstAndLast;
}

// The lines of code below will test your function when you run it from the
// command line with Node.js
console.log(addFirstToLast(['first', 'second', 'third']));
console.log(addFirstToLast(['golden', 'terrier']));
console.log(addFirstToLast(['cheerio']));
console.log(addFirstToLast([]));
```

The correct code is given above it will just create a string with the value from the first element of the array concatenated with the value from the last element.